# including secExt.h causes errors

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to include `secExt.h` in my C++ project and it gives me the error:

> error C2086: 'BOOLEAN SEC_ENTRY' : redefinition

How can I fix it?

Comment: What OS are you using? What library is this file part of?

Comment: win7, x64. It's supposed to be part of "Secur32.lib"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: from microsoft's docs, include [security.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not [secext.h].

original answer (before I googled the header name myself, no info given by OP):

---

if the header is yours, add

```
#pragma once
```

at the top.

if that doesn't work (there is reportedly a compiler on some IBM system or something that doesn't support `#pragma once`), then use a header guard.

if the header isn't yours, create a header wrapper like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <secExt.h>
```

then include your wrapper header instead of including [secExt.h] directly.

Comment: I already have" #pragma once", I also tried using a header guard but it didn't help.

Comment: you might get better answer in the future, if you include the relevant information in your question ;-)